# How to override a Plone event subscriber

Tags: overriding, plone

I need to extend a Plone product (Products.Poi) with a second product.
In the extension product i need to override a subscriber event of the original.
I tried to subscribe in an override.zcml an event with the same name but the second event don't override the first but all two are execute.

Here http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/five.grok/core-components/events seem that is not possible:

> Unlike adapters, you cannot override an event subscriber by using a more specific interface. Each and every applicable event subscriber will be executed when an event is fired.

Someone has a trick?

Thanks Alex

Comment: I would simply go for a monkey http://developer.plone.org/misc/monkeypatch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specified the overrides.zcml, you also need to register the zcml override in buildout? Take a look at: http://developer.plone.org/components/zcml.html?highlight=zcml#overrides It'd be something like: zcml = my.package-overrides

Additionally, you can try using the z3c.unconfigure package: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.unconfigure

Comment: You cannot override a subscriber with Overrides. Subscribers are a list of handlers, unlike adapters and utilities (so overrides replaces the existing registration); for subscribers the new handler is *added* instead.

Comment: Sorry Vangheem, I have seen later your answer. I opened this question to share the solution but i'm new and i have to wait 11 hours before answer a question posted by me :(

Answer (score 6):

Simone Orsi gave me a solution: [z3c.unconfigure](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.unconfigure).

This product permit to disable zcml configuration.

To use it, I executed this step on my extented Poi product:

1. Added "z3c.unconfigure" as install_requires in the setup.py
2. Create event.py with the new definition of update_tracker_watchers
3. In the overrides.zcml add this line to unconfigure Products.Poi.events.update_tracker_watchers and to register my new event

> `<include package="z3c.unconfigure" file="meta.zcml" />`
>   `<unconfigure>`
>       `<subscriber`
>           `for="Products.Poi.interfaces.ITracker`
>                     `Products.Archetypes.interfaces.IObjectEditedEvent"`
>           `handler="Products.Poi.events.update_tracker_watchers"`
>       `/>`
>       `</unconfigure>`
>   `<subscriber`
>       `for="Products.Poi.interfaces.ITracker`
>                 `Products.Archetypes.interfaces.IObjectEditedEvent"`
>       `handler=".events.update_tracker_watchers"`
>   `/>`